# Find row pairs in table with same value in given column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with ~700K rows and each row has a `REPEATED` field (avg. 150 values per id). I need to find pairs of ids which have any value in common.

my_table:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | v1 |
|  | v2 |
|  | v3 |
| B | v2 |
| C | v8 |
| D | v2 |
|  | v3 |

Output:

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | D |
| B | D |

I flattened the table (~100 million rows) and then joined it with itself to get id pairs where values are the same, but it keeps running for a long time. Is there an optimized way of doing this given the scale?

```
WITH

-- Results in ~100 million rows
flattened_table AS (
  SELECT 
    id,
    value,
  FROM
    my_table,
    UNNEST(value) AS value
)

SELECT 
  t1.id AS id1,
  t2.id AS id2,
FROM
  flattened_table t1,
  flattened_table t2
WHERE
  t1.id < t2.id      -- Get (A,B) only, don't need (B,A)
  AND t1.value = t2.value
```

Comment: How long is the "long time"? In the worst case that all your ids a value in common, you will have 700000^2 / 2 = 245 billion records in your output. It will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could try aggregating the ids grouped by the value, this avoids the join which could be slowing the process.

```
WITH
values_aggregated AS (
 SELECT
   value,
   ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids
 FROM
   my_table,
   UNNEST(value) AS value
 GROUP BY
   value
)

 SELECT
   ids[OFFSET(0)] AS id1,
   ids[OFFSET(1)] AS id2
 FROM
   values_aggregated
 WHERE
   ARRAY_LENGTH(ids) > 1 -- filter values that have more than 1 id 
and ids[OFFSET(0)]  < ids[OFFSET(1)]
```